# allow users to add users to azure enterprise application

Tags: azure

We have an Enterprise application, as an azure subscription owner I can add users to the application and assign them a role.

We would like to give other users the permissions to add users to our application but not give them full control of the Azure Subscription.

Can this be done, with and without an Azure Active Directory Premium subscription?

We have AzureAD connect setup, so we could manage this by groups but you need the premium subscription to work with groups.

Self-service may be an option but that asks for a group and we don't have premium.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can delegate the right to add users to applications to other users. However unfortunately to do so you need to grant the user you want to do this the Global Admin role in your Azure AD tenant. There is not currently a limited admin role that allows adding users to apps.